# SQL/MySQL - Select and return array column on one-to-many table join

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I return an array for a column which values are from an one-to-many join table?

That's my setup right now:

```
var user_id = 1;
var group_id = 1;

var sql = "SELECT * FROM users JOIN users_groups ON users.id = users_groups.user_id WHERE users.id = ? AND users_groups.group_id = ?";
var sqlVal = [ user_id, 1, group_id ];
```

Table users:

```
id|name|status

1,Paul,1
2,Nick,2
3,Claudia,1
```

Table users_groups:

```
user_id|group_id

1,1
1,2
1,3
2,3
3,2
3,3
```

And right now I'm getting:

Result rows (current):

```
[
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    lastname: 'Paul',
    status: 1,
    user_id: '1'
    group_id: '2'
  }
]
```

But how can I get?

Result rows (goal):

```
[
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    lastname: 'Paul',
    status: 1,
    user_id: '1',
    group_id: ['1', '2', '3']
  }
]
```

Comment: *`.. ARRAY JOIN ..`* - what is it? where you have taken this from? PS. [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: @Akina https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/array-join/ :-)

Comment: If so then add [clickhouse] tag but remove [mysql].

Comment: I have mysql ... sorry for posting

Comment: [MySQL : JOIN clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Mysql is a relational database, but you want it to return a json document output, not a tabular output that you expect from a relational database. You really should transform the results in your application logic from the row-by-row output into the json document you are looking for. You can try to use mysql to format the output (JSON_ARRAYAGG if you have mysql v8.0, combination of concat and group_concat for earlier versions), but it will depend on your client library how such return values are interpreted in your application.